# Execution of static blocks

Tags: java, static

Why is this code a compilation error?

```
class Test1{
    static {
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    static int x = 10;
}
```

While the below code compiles and runs fine?

```
class Test2{    
    static int x = 10;
    static {
        m1();
        System.out.println("base SB");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        m1();
        System.out.println("base main method");
    }

    public static void m1(){
        System.out.println(y);
    }   

    static int y = 20;
}
```

If it declares y here, why not in the previous code. 
The output of below code is:

```
0 
base SB 
20
base main method
```

I think Java does not support forward referencing.

Comment: What do you mean by "works fine"? What happens when you run `Test2`?

Comment: 0
base SB
20
base main method

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show this

Comment: A similar question appeared a couple of days ago (may have been instance initialisers). If you want the spec: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second test case prints zero first which I would assume would not be idiomatic for most people.

This is simply a case of the compiler not being smart enough to catch a probable mistake which you have made.

It is able to detect the forward reference in the first case -- lucky! If it didn't, your program would have printed zero at runtime since the variable would not have been initialized yet. So the compiler saved you from a probable bug.

It is not able to detect it in the second case, since you have introduced a level of indirection with the additional method call to `m1` -- unlucky!

In an ideal world, the second code sample wouldn't compile either.

Comment: Yes i meant it compiles fine.

Comment: @AndyTurner I can say that it works in such a manner which is likely to cause unusual behaviour, and difficult-to-diagnose bugs, which in my opinion is not fine.

Comment: I modified it to compiles and the answer helps. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Michael, I do not think there is a forward reference in java.

Comment: @Payal, First case error occurred due to not find any declaration for x. Second case working fine as static variable and block got execute in the order in which it appears.

Answer (score 4):

It may be an unsatisfying answer, but this is just how the language was defined, specifically [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.3).

> The restrictions above are designed to catch, at compile time, circular or otherwise malformed initializations

But you can get around the restriction quite easily like in the question, or just by using `Test21.x` instead of just `x`, so it is not particularly robust:

```
class Test21{
    static {
        // This is legal, but it is uninitialized, and thus prints 0.
        System.out.println(Test21.x);
    }
    static int x=10;
}
```

On balance, it is probably better to force you to jump through a small hoop, to make you stop and think about what you are doing, and only to proceed if you *really* intend to do that.

Ultimately, the language can't entirely stop you shooting yourself in the foot. It can only make it harder to do so.